# Regularization parameter setting for Randomized Regression in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am using sklearn Randomized Regression, such as [Randomized Logistic Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RandomizedLogisticRegression.html). Because randomized logistic regression uses L1-penalty, it is require to set the regularization parameter C(or alpha in Lasso).

To find good value for C, I usually used simple GridSearchCV like below.

But RandomizedLogisticRegression() does not support GridSearchCV, because it contains the bootstrapping. Instead, I tried to use typical LogisticRegression with GridSearchCV.

```
params = {'C':[0.1, 1, 10]}
logi = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
clf = GridSearchCV(logi, params, cv=10)
```

I could get C by this way, however, no attribute was selected when I apply this C value to Randomized logistic regression. Maybe the selected C by GridSearchCV was quite low.

So, I would like to know that whether there are any other good way for determining the fair value of C(or alpha), when using Randomized regression.

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810051/how-do-i-found-the-lowest-regularization-parameter-c-using-randomized-logistic) before, but I think that answer was for typical regression.

Can anyone give me an idea please?

Comment: What about cross-validation?

Comment: Unfortunately, using LogisticRegressionCV() produced the similar result as GridSearchCV(). The best C value was too small, and the coefficients of each features were all 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `RandomizedLogisticRegression` is used for feature selection, it would need to be cross validated as part of a pipeline. You can apply `GridSearchCV` to a `Pipeline` which contains it as a feature selection step along with your classifier of choice. An example might look like:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
  ('fs', RandomizedLogisticRegression()),
  ('clf', LogisticRegression())
])

params = {'fs__C':[0.1, 1, 10]}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, params)
```

Comment: Thank you again for your advice! I did not think of pipeline, but it seems to be a nice idea. With this approach, I may use other kind of classifiers instead of L1-Logistic regression. I would try this.

Comment: May I ask one more question? If the class label is balanced, I may use accuracy as a scoring method of classifier. But if it is biased(about 100:20), which methods will be better? I am using roc_auc, but I think it is not enough, and it could not be combined with LOOCV. Is there any other scoring method to recommend?

Comment: Usually the overall scoring depends on the application. ROC AUC is good if the rank order of the probabilities is meaningful. Log loss is useful if you care more about the probabilities being a good likelihood estimate. In terms of k-fold or leave one out cross validation, you might cross predict the entire dataset and then apply AUC ROC afterward.

Comment: Thank you very much David. Your advices were very helpful for me.

Comment: This works well with smaller sample, but produced error 'ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(500, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.' with my dataset, althogh I used wide range of Cs. I think it was not possible to find important features with randomized logistic regression in this case.

Comment: You might try removing some of the lower C values.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. If one of the C values(maybe the lowest) let regression select no feature, the pipeline seems to stop by that error.